# JavsScript. Select all invisible elements. (WebKit only)

Tags: javascript, webkit

I'm looking for a way to select all invisible elements.
Something like `webkit.window.document.querySelectorAll("p:hidden")`.

For example, in html

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p>123</p>
  <p style="display:none;"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I can select invisible with `"p[style*='display:none']"`, but it doesn't work if space exists between `display` and `none`. Like `<p style="display:    none;"></p>`.

In summary, I need a way to select all invisible elements using WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect if an element is hidden is to check its [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight):

```
return (this.offsetHeight > 0)
```

Comment: It is better to use return this.style.display != 'none'

Comment: @ArunAravind no, only checking this.style.display would be a mistake.

Comment: Nope. If you want to hide an element you should do it intentionally. There will be many other elements which are empty and were added just for styling purposes even as the target of :empty selector.

Comment: Then how are you going to hide the td's ??

Comment: Why would anybody want to hide the td's and then hide the table and then check for hidden td's

Comment: @ArunAravind read this to understand the difference between hidden and display none: http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery for selecting elements, below code would fulfill your requirement

```
var allHiddenElements = $("body *").filter(
    function() { 
        return $(this).css("display") == "none";
    });
```

Comment: I do not use jQuery in that case. Just load HTML into WebKit object and then process it. Maybe WebKit supports something similar to jQuery :hidden.

Comment: any particular reason for not using jquery and only using webkit (after all I suppose you are writing javascript code)?

Comment: I'm indexing some classified boards. Inside desktop application I load html pages, then send loaded html code into WekKit component. So I need clean up html before processing (remove js, invisible elements). It is possible to inject jQuery code into html, but maybe WebKit natively supports that selectors, would be faster and better.

Comment: -1 this will only select the elements with a display property equal to none. You should use the :hidden selector instead http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/